# adding videos to a website

Tags: html, video, photos

Alright I´m gonna try to be a bit more specific.

The website is not yet up and running, but I will be using a hosting site such as youtube. 
What I meant to say is that I tried adding a video using the following code

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
<source src="parklane.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
<object data="parklane.mp4" width="320" height="240">
<embed src="parklane.swf" width="320" height="240">
```

Comment: what do you want to do ? what is your markup ? what have you done so far ? what do you want do add ? what do you want to do with that ?

Comment: Considered HTML5? http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_video_dom.asp

Comment: If you're using YouTUbe or similar, they'll provide you with a nice cross-browser and cross-device embed code.

Comment: If you will be using youtube, why don't you start by embedding a you tube video?

Comment: I want to upload both small and large videos. Some will be high-definition and others might be low. I thought that html alone would not be a strong enough dev to handle so many videos. 

I´m not sure embedding videos via youtube is the way to go. I mean for instance, if you take a look at a site as IGN.com  they both have thumbnail videos as well as full sized ones. Is that possible using YouTube? Or do I need another solution? 

And also, videos used via YouTube limits you when it comes to advertisement.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using YouTube then they provide a nice embedding code for you to add to your page.

e.g `<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/teHfyby_veU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

This will embed the video from this page `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=teHfyby_veU` on your site at 420px wide and 315px high.

If you want to dynamically add them from a database or list of video ids you just need to change the id in the embedding code.

e.g `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=**teHfyby_veU**`

`<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/**teHfyby_veU**" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

You can adjust the dimensions by changing the width and height of the iFrame.

If you need anything more than these basics then you might want to have a look at the youtube api - http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/overview.html